# Bootstrap 3 Nav Dropdown inside dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my fiddle, `[a link](http://jsfiddle.net/snayyer/y48xr/4/)!`

See how the dropdown in nav behaves in responsive mode. I need to add sub dropdown inside the existing dropdown. like the one shown here http://demo.theme-fusion.com/ in responsive mode.

But in normal desktop version I need to make same nav bar as in http://www.cnet.com/

can any one please suggest me how to make same nav bar for different behaviors ?